# Different serialVersionUID with different Java Versions

Tags: java, deserialization

i have a weird Problem with the Java serialization/de-serialization.

Besides all other problems with serialization and the proper usage of serialVersionUIDs such a behaviour is completely new to me:

On one machine my software is running on (openSuse 13.1) a update switched the Java version to Java 8. Now, i get a java.io.InvalidClassException if i try to reopen a project file of the software (which is a serialized Java Object) because one of the included classes has the wrong serialVersionUID. The weird thing is, that these class is a class from an external library and has not changed several month (but has no hard coded serialVersionUID field).

If i switch back to Java 7 on that machine, the error do not occur. I can reproduce that error on other machines with openSuse 13.1 + Java 8 but not with machines with Windows or other Linux distributions (like Ubuntu) with Java 8 (or Java 7).

On all machines the official sun/oracle JRE package is installed.

So, has anybody faced that problem at any time? I do not think that it is a bug in Java 8, because it only occurs on an openSuse 13.1 machine. But how could the guys from openSuse mess up their system such, that java would hash the class in a different way as before (as Java has not changed that process in a new version)?

EDIT:
To be clear, the class who causes the problem is from an external library. It has not changed in month. And the solution can not be to define a serialVersionUID, because that error has some other sources and would still be there. And i think, it would not stop with this class, it would affect all classes from my used libraries with no defined serialVersionUID

EDIT2:
Here is the exact error:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.util.Pair; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 7664847375082415686, local class serialVersionUID = -638192081897624765
```

On all other machines i can test it, the class has the hashed serialVersionUID 7664847375082415686, only openSuse 13.1 + Java 8 get a result of -638192081897624765

Comment: This is because some user has been used the software before you update the java version. Let the users kick off before doing major upgrades.

Comment: How would that impact the hashing method for classes on runtime?

Comment: It wouldn't, even if the hashing change the code will have just a different signature.

Comment: So i do not get your point.

Comment: We're experiencing a similar issue. Windows 7 with Java 8 fails, but my machine with Windows 8 and Java 8 works fine. This wasn't a problem when we were on Java 6. In our case, the failure occurs when RMIC classes are being loaded.

Comment: @Thargor, Did you ever reach a resolution for this issue? I am really curious because we are going through a similar issue.

Comment: @hfontanez: No. I never find a solution for that problem. As it is limited (at the moment) to this special Java Version / OS Version combination we did not follow this problem anymore.

Answer (score 1):

> has anybody faced that problem at any time?

You have done well to have not found this issue.  All the IDEs have a warning for Serializable classes with a serialVersionUID AFAIK. It's a common issue, or rather it is common for people to hardcode the serialVersionUID so they don't see it.  Note: eclipse and Oracle JDKs produce different UID for the same version of Java.

> because it only occurs on an openSuse 13.1 machine.

This would be very surprising.  The same version of Java should produce the same serialVersionUID on every OS.

Note: you can set the serialVersionUID to any thing you need. e.g. say you need to read an object with a given serialVersionUID, you can set it to the expect UID and it will attempt to read any version you want.

Comment: But this is a problem of the JRE, not the JDK, as i run the software from a JAR file, without any JDK involvement.
Yes, i know, but it happens right now here. I have no idea what is going on...
As the class is inside a library i had to change that in the code of the library an build it new. But i think it will not stop with this one class from this library. My own classes have a "hard coded" serialVersionUID

Comment: @Thargor Again, the JDK and the JRE of the same version should behave the same on all OSes.  The code to do this is platform independent.

Comment: I know =). That is the reason, why i ask that question here. That project started in Java 5 and till now, that was never ever a problem, as java do not change the method to hash the classes (with the SHA-1 algorithm, which is hopefully implemented in Java and is not done with an system methode)

Comment: @Thargor This is very popular digest to sign a Java bytecode, and hashes are stored independently in the manifest files.

Answer (score 0):

We found out a while back that the source of our problem was because we had an active service running in the background that was compiled with an older version of Java.  This service was set to start automatically. Therefore, rebooting the computer didn't work for obvious reasons.  This was the result of a defect on our software uninstaller.  We often install builds on our machines to test fielded versions of our software. In this particular case, in one machine there was an active service that was conflicting with our software; even though we were running it from Eclipse.

I would suggest to anyone experiencing similar issues to verify that an old service is not creating the conflict. Make sure you uninstall or disable the suspect service and try again.